# Low accuracy when training MNIST data on a custom neural network

Tags: c++, neural-network, eigen, mnist

I've written a neural network in C++ that uses the Eigen library, and I'm trying to test out its accuracy by training it on the MNIST handwriting data. I train the network but get only ~10% accuracy when validating it against the test data before and after training. It should be around 90% if I'm not mistaken. I'm not sure why training isn't working, and I'd like to figure that out. I've checked the flow through a debugger and also double checked I process the input data correctly. Here's my relevant implementation code, the rest is available on [this repository](https://github.com/shans96/basic-neural-network):

Network.cpp

```
Network::Network(const std::vector<int> layer_data)
    : weights(0), biases(0)
{
    initialize_layers(layer_data);
    generate_weights();
    generate_biases();
}

Network::Network(const std::vector<int> layer_data, 
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> network_weights, std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> network_biases)
{
    initialize_layers(layer_data);
    weights = network_weights;
    biases = network_biases;
}

void Network::initialize_layers(std::vector<int> layer_data)
{
    layers = layer_data;
    non_input_layers = std::vector<int>(layers.begin() + 1, layers.end());
}

void Network::generate_biases()
{
    biases.reserve(non_input_layers.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < non_input_layers.size(); i++)
    {
        biases.push_back(Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(non_input_layers[i], 1));
    }
}

void Network::generate_weights()
{
    weights.reserve(layers.size() - 1);
    for (auto it = layers.begin(); it != layers.end() - 1; it++)
    {
        weights.push_back(Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(*next(it), *it));
    }
}

std::tuple<Eigen::MatrixXd, std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd>, std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd>> Network::feed_forward(Eigen::VectorXd input)
{
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> net_inputs;
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> activations;
    net_inputs.reserve(non_input_layers.size() - 1);
    activations.reserve(non_input_layers.size());
    activations.push_back(input);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < non_input_layers.size(); i++)
    {
        input = network_calc::multiply_matrices(weights[i], input) + biases[i];
        net_inputs.push_back(input);
        input = input.unaryExpr([] (double x) {
                return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x));
            });
        activations.push_back(input);
    }
    return std::make_tuple(input, net_inputs, activations);
}

std::pair<std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd>, std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd>> Network::backpropagate(Eigen::MatrixXd input, Eigen::MatrixXd expected_output)
{
    auto feed_forward_results = (*this).feed_forward(input);
    Eigen::MatrixXd calculated_output = std::get<0>(feed_forward_results);
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> net_inputs = std::get<1>(feed_forward_results);
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> activations = std::get<2>(feed_forward_results);

    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> cloned_weights(weights);
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> cloned_biases(biases);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < layers[layers.size() - 1]; i++)
    {
        cloned_biases[cloned_biases.size() - 1](i, 0) = network_calc::result_difference(expected_output(i, 0), calculated_output(i, 0)) * 
            network_calc::sigmoid_derivative(net_inputs[net_inputs.size() - 1](i));
    }

    Eigen::MatrixXd delta = cloned_biases[cloned_biases.size() - 1];

    cloned_weights[cloned_weights.size() - 1] = network_calc::multiply_matrices(delta, activations[activations.size() - 2].transpose());

    for (size_t i = non_input_layers.size() - 1; !(i == 0); i--)
    {
        Eigen::MatrixXd partial_calc = net_inputs[i - 1].unaryExpr([] (double x) {
            return network_calc::sigmoid_derivative(x);
        });

        delta  = network_calc::multiply_matrices(weights[i].transpose(), delta).cwiseProduct(partial_calc);

        cloned_biases[i - 1] = delta; 
        cloned_weights[i - 1] = network_calc::multiply_matrices(delta, activations[i - 1].transpose());
    }

    return std::make_pair(cloned_biases, cloned_weights);
}

void Network::mini_batch_gradient_descent(double alpha, int epochs, int batch_size, std::vector<xy_data> training_data)
{
    auto rng = std::default_random_engine{};
    std::vector<xy_data> mini_batch;
    mini_batch.reserve(batch_size);
    if (training_data.size() < batch_size)
    {
        std::cout << "Warning: training data size is less than the batch size. Batch size will be changed to match training data size.\n";
        batch_size = training_data.size();
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < epochs; i++)
    {
        std::shuffle(std::begin(training_data), std::end(training_data), rng);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < batch_size; j++)
        {
            mini_batch.push_back(training_data[j]);;
        }

        update_weights_biases(mini_batch, alpha);
        // Perform prediction on the last example just to check
        Eigen::MatrixXd new_predicted_output = std::get<2>((*this).feed_forward(training_data.back().first)).back();

        std::cout << "Epoch " << std::to_string(i) << ", "
            << "SSE: " << std::to_string(network_calc::sum_squared_error(new_predicted_output, training_data.back().second)) << ".\n";
    }
}

std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> Network::get_weights()
{
    return weights;
}

std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> Network::get_biases()
{
    return biases;
}

std::vector<int> Network::get_layers()
{
    return layers;
}

void Network::update_weights_biases(std::vector<xy_data> batch, double alpha)
{
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> delta_weights = network_calc::created_zeroed_layers(&weights);
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> delta_biases = network_calc::created_zeroed_layers(&biases);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < batch.size(); i++)
    {
        auto backprop_output_pair = (*this).backpropagate(batch[i].first, batch[i].second);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < backprop_output_pair.first.size(); j++)
        {
            delta_weights[j] += backprop_output_pair.second[j];
            delta_biases[j] += backprop_output_pair.first[j];
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < weights.size(); i++)
    {
        weights[i] -= (alpha / batch.size()) * delta_weights[i];
        biases[i] -= (alpha / batch.size()) * delta_biases[i];
    }
}
```

To load the MNIST data, I use [this](https://github.com/wichtounet/mnist) repository, normalize the pixel intensity between 0-1, and then train/validate it as follows:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd convert_mnist_image_to_vector(std::vector<uint8_t> image)
{
    // Normalize range to 0,1
    Eigen::VectorXd input(784);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < image.size(); i++)
    {
        input(i) = (image[i]) 
            / (255.0);
    }
    return input;
}

Eigen::MatrixXd convert_mnist_label_to_vector(double value)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd output = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(10, 1);
    output((int)value, 0) = 1.0;
    return output;
}

std::vector<xy_data> prepare_mnist_output_data()
{
    // Create output vectors with a value of 1 where the activation happened, and turn the input vectors into eigen vectors
    // Load MNIST data
    mnist::MNIST_dataset<> dataset =
        mnist::read_dataset<>();

    std::vector<xy_data> mnist_examples;
    mnist_examples.reserve(dataset.training_labels.size());

    std::cout << "Nbr of training images = " << dataset.training_images.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Nbr of training labels = " << dataset.training_labels.size() << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataset.training_labels.size(); i++)
    {
        Eigen::MatrixXd input = convert_mnist_image_to_vector(dataset.training_images[i]);
        Eigen::MatrixXd output = convert_mnist_label_to_vector(dataset.training_labels[i]);
        mnist_examples.push_back(std::make_pair(input, output));
        //std::cout << i << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "MNIST data preparation complete." << "\n";
    return mnist_examples;
}

std::vector<xy_data> prepare_mnist_test_data()
{
    // Create output vectors with a value of 1 where the activation happened, and turn the input vectors into eigen vectors
    // Load MNIST data
    mnist::MNIST_dataset<> dataset =
        mnist::read_dataset<>();

    std::vector<xy_data> mnist_examples;
    mnist_examples.reserve(dataset.test_labels.size());

    std::cout << "Nbr of test images = " << dataset.test_images.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Nbr of test labels = " << dataset.test_labels.size() << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataset.test_labels.size(); i++)
    {
        Eigen::MatrixXd input = convert_mnist_image_to_vector(dataset.test_images[i]);
        Eigen::MatrixXd output = convert_mnist_label_to_vector(dataset.test_labels[i]);
        mnist_examples.push_back(std::make_pair(input, output));
        //std::cout << i << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "MNIST data preparation complete." << "\n";
    return mnist_examples;
}
int argmax(Eigen::MatrixXd mat)
{
    //helper method intended only for mnist
    double greatest = 0;
    int greatest_idx = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (mat(i, 0) > greatest)
        {
            greatest_idx = i;
        }
    }
    return greatest_idx;
}

void validate(Network *network, std::vector<xy_data> test_data)
{
    int matches = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < test_data.size(); i++)
    {
        auto result = std::get<2>(network->feed_forward(test_data[i].first));
        int expected_val = argmax(test_data[i].second);
        int activation_val = argmax(result.back());
        if (activation_val == expected_val)
        {
            matches++;
            std::cout << matches << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Network mnist_network = Network(std::vector<int> { 784, 100, 10 });
    std::vector<xy_data> dataset = prepare_mnist_output_data();
    std::vector<xy_data> test_dataset = prepare_mnist_test_data();

    validate(&mnist_network, test_dataset);
    mnist_network.mini_batch_gradient_descent(3.0, 30, 10, dataset);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At first glance I can't find anything wrong with your code. What I would personally do (which means it might not be the ideal thing to do) is test, maybe even unit test those functions one by one to verify they do what I expect them to do and hopefully at least one doesn't so it can be fixed.

Comment: Another idea would be to use a higher level library like [DLib](http://dlib.net/ml.html), use its neural network. It has nice customization support, so you can replace those things you wanna do yourself, like for example a custom activation function, custom layers etc

Comment: Previous comments are assuming that you used your debugger correctly and didn't oversee anything, which could have been spotted by using it.

Comment: The function `convert_mnist_label_to_vector` has to convert the labels from your dataset into a vector, whose elements are 0,1,...,9, am I right? But it seems that it sets all the label to 1. If this function is correct, I think that the problem could be in how you set the algorithm to train your data, i.e. the choice fo alpha, the nr of epochs and so on.